# How are some electronics with physical on/off switches turn off with a tune/message?

Tags: switches, audio

Like this:
A toy says "See you later!" when the switch is turned off.

The Bose Qc35 plays tones then shuts off when the switch is turned off.

How can I mimic this in my BT speaker circuit?

Comment: A) are you sure these switches are indeed interrupting the power supply ? B) a medium size Al electrolytic can keep small stuff powered for a few seconds.

Comment: @tobalt they are SPST slide switches.

Comment: That doesn't tell that they break the power supply. They could also just pull a control signal up/down that sends the circuit into sleep mode

Comment: These days few devices actually have a physical button that disconnects the power supply. And they're not needed, circuits can be designed such that they enter a "power down" state where they're still connected to the power supply (or battery) but consume so little power that it is not needed to disconnect the battery.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdoHD6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple example circuit.*

It's a common feature on microcontrollers and other devices that there is a low powered sleep mode. Notice in Figure 1 that the battery is permanently connected to V+ but the on-off switch only signals to the device whether to be on or off. Switching off will initiate switching off peripherals or doing some sequence of events (such as playing a tune in your case) before going into low-power mode. Switching on will cause a wake-up event to bring the controller back to life.

In your case the chips are probably one-time programmed. Your Bluetooth speaker circuit is unlikely to be customisable. I'd recommend finding another project!